# how can i calculate the average days in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I need to calculate the average days within the specified datetime values in sql server which involves the logic day+(hh + mm + ss + mi) as the average time(days).
can anybody help me?

thanks in advance...

Comment: sorry, it's early here and I haven't had coffee yet. Can you give more details?  What do you mean by average days within datetime values?  Is there a range of dates?

Comment: oh..good morning...Actually i have to calculate an average number of days for range of datetime values to be given.say for instance consider two datetime columns as @startdatetime and @enddatetime.ex:@startdatetime = '2008-09-03 10:00:00.000' and @enddatetime = '2008-09-03 11:05:05.005'.I want to calculate the total no of days within that range of datetime values.like 2.5 and blah blah blah...

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate)
FROM myTable
```

That will give you the number of days between two dates.

You can get the average with the [AVG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx) function:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate))
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

And just in case your enddate may be null, try this

```
select case when (SubscriptionEnd is null) 
then datediff (day,SubscriptionStart,getdate())
else datediff (day,SubscriptionStart,SubscriptionEnd)
end as 'totaldays'
from [dbo].[whatever]
```